# How to handle Daylight savings time DST in Pandas without getting AmbiguousTime or NonExistantTime Errors

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timezone, dst

I work with large datasets where daylight savings time (DST) has to be handled.
Here is a solution that I found indirectly here on stackoverflow. I am trying to answer this question more directly so others can find it faster.

Question and setup.
Basically how do you convert a datetime column in pandas to a specific timezone or to UTC. This is easy if there are no datetimes with DST. But with DST then there has to be a few extra steps.

Dataset:

```
2012-03-24 23:00;    4.9741
2012-03-25 00:00;    4.9443
2012-03-25 01:00;    4.9443
2012-03-25 02:00;    4.9160
2012-03-25 03:00;    4.8865
2012-03-25 04:00;    4.8865
2012-03-25 05:00;    4.8584
2012-10-27 22:00;    2.1982
2012-10-27 23:00;    2.1982
2012-10-28 00:00;    2.1982
2012-10-28 01:00;    2.1839
2012-10-28 02:00;    2.1839
2012-10-28 03:00;    2.1982
2012-10-28 04:00;    2.1839
2012-10-28 05:00;    2.1839
```

Now there is data with both spring and autumn DST
The data comes as csv and is loaded and prepped:

```
import pandas 

df = pandas.read_csv('data_file_path', sep=';', encoding='utf-8')
def column_names(df):
    df.columns=['Time', 'Value']
    return df

df = column_names(df)

def change_str_column_to_float(df):
    df['Value'] = pandas.to_numeric(df['Value'])
    return df

df = change_str_column_to_float(df)
```

Data is now cleaned and prepped. Now onto how to convert the Time to UTC time or a specific timezone.

Comment: Your dataset example does not seem to contain any DST transition, so if these date/times represent Norway time, they are *wrong*, no?

Comment: The transitions are 2012-03-25 for spring and 2012-10-28 for autumn both of which are in the data. As these where the dates where I got problems. I just double checked here: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2012.html

Comment: I know there should have been DST transitions on these dates - but I don't see them represented in your example. There should be a missing / duplicate hour.

Comment: They come when you apply df['Time'].dt.tz_convert(timeZone) to them, as soon as I do that then I get errors about Nonexistant time or ambiguous time. Thats why I felt I needed a clear example explaining that I have to first assign utc tzinfo before I add timeZone info.

Comment: as I said in my first comment, if you receive these dates, and they represent time in Oslo time zone, they are wrong. That is why in fact you *should* get and error in my opinion. If they represent UTC, they are fine, you can localize to UTC and then convert to Oslo tz. That will not give you non-existent time errors.

Comment: The data comes from an analog sensor, thats setup in Norwegian time. But in reality it just counts once an hour. Therefor there are no missing or duplicated times. If it was digital I would get the data like you say, but not the way this is setup.

Comment: the long-term solution is simple: configure the sensor to use UTC. You can unambiguously convert that to time in any time zone. The short-term solution for your data could be to localize to UTC, add/subtract a constant offset (e.g. two hours), *then* convert to the time zone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The data comes from Norway but does not have Norwegian timezone applied when received. I want to apply the Norwegian timezone, and if necessary convert it to UTC
So there are two possible solutions. Here are both:

```
import pytz

def add_norwegian_timezone(df):
    timeZone = pytz.timezone("Europe/Oslo")
    df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.tz_localize('UTC')
    df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.tz_convert(timeZone)
    return df

def convert_to_utc(df):
    timeZone = pytz.timezone("Europe/Oslo")
    df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.tz_localize('UTC')
    df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.tz_convert(timeZone)
    df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.tz_convert('UTC')
    return df
```

The thing I found interesting is that when no timezone is defined in a pandas datetime column, you have to first apply a UTC timezone (df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.tz_localize('UTC')). After that you apply the actual timezone of that dataset (df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.tz_convert(timeZone)). Then you have your data in the local timezone, in this case Norwegian. If you then want your data to be in UTC, you convert it back to UTC (df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.tz_convert('UTC')).

Its strange you have to do these steps but I find its the only way to get pandas to account for DST without getting either AmbiguousTime or NonExistantTime errors.

I am pretty sure this is correct, when I run it, the datetimes are converted correctly and no errors are found. But I would love feedback to make sure I am sharing the correct information to the community, and have not missed something.

Thanks :)

Comment: btw. you don't need to import pytz explicitly; strings work just fine - e.g. `dt.tz_convert("Europe/Oslo")`.